# I have a directory with the list of files. I have to list files and find the file with maximum file size and insert the largest file in the mongodb

Tags: node.js

I have a directory with the list of files. I have to list files and find the file with maximum file size and insert the largest file in the mongodb.I have found out the maximum size file,but unable to print in console.It displays undefined.

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
var sleep = require('system-sleep');
var fsCompare = require('fs-compare');
var statssize = 0;
var foundFile;
var directorypath = path.join(__dirname, 'directory');
var fsfiles = fs.readdir(directorypath, function(err, data) {
    var temp = [];
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    data.forEach(function(file) {
        var fileSizeInMegabytes;
        var pathtofiles = 'directory' + '\\' + file;
        fs.stat(pathtofiles, function(err, stats) {
            // sleep(5000);
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            if (statssize < stats.size) {
                statssize = stats.size;
                foundFile = pathtofiles;
            }
            fileSizeInMegabytes = statssize / 1000000.0;
        });
    });
    console.log(foundFile + "foundfile");
    console.log(statssize + "stats of file");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is asynchronous, i.e your console.log get executed before `fs.stat()` function returns any value.

```
console.log(foundFile + "foundfile");
console.log(statssize + "stats of file");
```

These should only be written inside the callback func of `fs.stat()` i.e right below this line

```
fileSizeInMegabytes = statssize / 1000000.0;
```

(y)